# difference between rows among each other, sum and sort python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to calculate the difference between each different row elementwise, not only the following row. So all the possible row pairs and combinations should be calculated. The result should be saved in a different dataframe. At the end the sum of the values of the new rows should be calculated (one column). The total sum of that column needs to be less as possible. The goal is to find out the best way to get the best new order of the rows. At the end the rows should be ordered in a way, that differences calculated elementwise and summed up for each row, should be as less as possible.

What I did so far was only calculating the difference of the following row:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
matrix=np.random.randint(4, size=100).reshape(10,10)
matrix=pd.DataFrame(matrix)

#difference of the next following rows only absolute values
diffmatrix=((matrix.diff(axis=0)).fillna(0)).abs()
#counting differences
diffcount=diffmatrix.sum(axis=1)
```

If something is unclear, I will update my post again.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "difference between the rows"? The difference elementwise, the difference between their sums, etc? Also, it's not clear by what you mean when you say that the total sum should be as *small* as possible. I think the total sum difference will be invariant if you're talking about summing all the possible differences between all pairs of rows: order isn't going to matter.

Comment: @MattMessersmith at the end the rows should be ordered in a way, the differences calculated elementwise and summed up for each row, should be as less as possible. Is that clearer ? sorry for my bad english

Comment: But I thought you said you need the differences between all pairs of rows, not just row to row? Or did I misunderstand you? To quote you "So all the possible row pairs and combinations should be calculated". If you do it for all pairs of rows, that final sum will be the same regardless of the order of the rows.

Comment: @MattMessersmith you are right I said that. It was wrong from me. I want that the difference of the next following rows calculated elementwise have at the end smallest difference. The Final would not be important that's right.

Comment: Maybe a small example would be helpful. Can you craft one by hand and show the input/output that you are expecting?

Comment: @MattMessersmith I hope the picture above can might help a bit, in that case I only looked for the difference of the first row to the 2) and 6) according to that the 6) row needs to follow up the first one, but I want all combinations and the difference ideal should zero in the matrix right and after that the rows need to be reorded. If this is not clear enough, I will rethink how to explain delete this and ad new post.

Comment: Assuming that your criterion is sth like sum of abs differences of adjacent pairs in the output, this looks like a variant of the [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem): Your rows are graph vertices of a fully connected graph, and the abs differences are edge costs. You want to find the shortest path that visits each vertex exactly once. The only difference is that your path is not closed. Nonetheless, this still has exponential complexity in the number of rows, so you will have to rely on heuristics (see e.g. the link)

Comment: @MatthiasOssadnik good point it really looks like that, now I would need a starting point for one heuristic algorithm, do you have any idea how this could look like ?

Comment: check out the wikipedia link above, I don't have much experience with this. Sometimes simulated annealing can be OK for this kind of problem, but it can be tricky to tune.